# Define polygon across the 180 meridian in DotSpatial

Tags: polygon, c#, dotspatial, antimeridian

I am new to DotSpatial and I try to define a polygon that crosses the 180 meridian by following:

```
        FeatureSet fs = new FeatureSet(FeatureType.Polygon);
        Coordinate[] coord = new Coordinate[5];
        coord[0] = new Coordinate(30, 48);
        coord[1] = new Coordinate(120, 45);
        coord[2] = new Coordinate(-170, 64);
        coord[3] = new Coordinate(30, 70);
        coord[4] = new Coordinate(30, 48);
        Polygon pg = new Polygon(coord);
        pg.Normalize();
        fs.Features.Add(pg);
        fs.Projection = DotSpatial.Projections.KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984;
        fs.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/shp/test2.shp"), true);
```

However, when I check the shapefile, the polygon comes out to be

[image]

If I draw the same polygon in SQL Server with

```
DECLARE @Poly geography =   
  geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((30 48, 120 45, -170 64, 30 70, 30 48))', 4326)  
SELECT @Poly
```

I can see the polygon shown as

[image]

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue in DotSpatial?